# Android cant reach "setOnClickListener" method by using getMethod ,getMethods,getDeclaredMethod

Tags: android, reflection, getmethod

I have Button and I can get any of its methods such as getText,setText ... using

```
Method mth = myButton.getClass().getMethod("getText", parameterTypes);
```

but when I try to get  "setOnClickListener" method using the same code
    `Method mth = myButton.getClass().getMethod("setOnClickListener", parameterTypes);` I am getting Exception : "NoSuchMethodException" Exception.

What I have tried:

send empty params

```
Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class[] {};
`Method mth = myButton.getClass().getMethod("setOnClickListener", parameterTypes);` NOT working the same Exception:  "NoSuchMethodException"

i tried to get all the methods and identify it by name.
Method[] arrMethods = objElem.getClass().getMethods();

Method listener = getMethodByName(arrMethods,"setOnClickListener");

public Method getMethodByName(Method[] arrMethods,String MethodName)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arrMethods.length;i++)
        {
            if(arrMethods[i].getName() == MethodName)
            {
                return arrMethods[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

the function actually not found .
its clearly that I have some misunderstanding here .
may be its not posible to reach this method??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what

```
if(arrMethods[i].getName() == MethodName)
```

is really what do you want. This condition will be true if the arrMethods[i].getName() returns the reference to the **same object** referred to by MethodName.

I think you would check if the **strings** are equal:

```
if(arrMethods[i].getName().equals(MethodName)
```

Comment: the function works when i write this myBtn.setOnClickListener(elemListener);so the function name is "setOnClickListener" like "setText","getText" ... so I wold like to know why my code not working if to this specific function there is different name or it cant be access in this way

Answer (score 0):

You should provide correct parameter types

```
Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class[] {View.OnClickListener.class};
```

You can always view parameter at class/method docs [View.setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))